Comparison between height of an ideals from a Cohen-Macaulay ring to another Cohen-Macaulay ring under a special surjective ring homomorphism.
Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism, where $R$ and $S$ are Cohen-Macaulay rings. Suppose that the kernel of $f$ is generated by a regular sequence. We are asked to determine whether the following statement is true or false:
For any ideal $I$ of $R$, we have $\text{ht} (I) \geq \text{ht} (f(I))$.
I am learning Cohen-Macaulay rings for the first time and familiar with some special properties of that ring. I think we need to use here these properties that $R/\text{Ker} f \cong S$ and in a Cohen-Macaulay ring $R$ if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then we have  $\text{dim} (R) = \text{dim}  (R/I) + \text{ht} (I)$.  But I don't understand how to use it.

Let $\dim R=d, \dim S=e, ht(I)=p, ht(f(I))=q$. So, $\dim R/I=d-p$. Since $S/f(I)$ is a quotient of $R/I$ by $d-e$ elements, we see that $\dim S/f(I)\geq e-p$. We also have $e=\dim S/f(I)+q$, which gives $e\geq e-p+q$ and so $p\geq q$.

Where did you use the fact that kernel is generated by regular sequence ?

@SwarajKoley The kernel is generated by exactly $d-e$ elements.
